# Select based on date not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `end` >= '2016-06-20 00:00:00' AND end <= '2016-06-26 00:00:00'
```

If for example end = `2016-06-26 19:00:00` the sql doesn't get this row and I don't understand why. Can you help me please ? 
Normally should work correctly

Comment: because `19 > 0`. use `23:59:59` if you want to include the last day. or use the date only, without the time.

Comment: If `end='2016-06-26 19:00:00'` then there at least one record must exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing full dates & times. and `00:00:00` comes **BEFORE** `19:00:00`, therefore your 19:00:00 value is outside the specified range.

if you want to include all times on a particular date, then compare only the date values, e.g.

```
WHERE date(end) BETWEEN '2016-06-20' AND '2016-06-26'
```

Comment: `end` is a reserve word and should be escaped accordingly.

Comment: it's just an example snippet, so I'm not particularly concerned about making it 100% accurate - it's unusable by itself anyways.

Comment: But should be pointed in case OP don't know it. So the comment is an addition pointer to the answer.

Comment: OP is better off including appropriate times on the bounds, `DATE()` will result in ignoring any indexes (now or in the future) on `end`.